# How can I stop a media from playing in popcron.js

Tags: javascript, popcornjs

I have and audio that is being played and I want to stop it from playing once the user clicks on a button. I have tried `popcorn.mute()`, but it does not give the result I want. I want something like `popcorn.stop();`

Comment: try `popcorn.pause();`

Comment: no it does not give me what I want. I want to stop or destroy the video(or the audio). I don't want to just pause it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to really destroy the video, you need to make sure that a) it's not playing and b) there are no references to it anywhere in memory, including the DOM. That way, the Javascript engine can garbage-collect it. Just to be extra thorough, we'll clear out the `src`.

```
var video = popcorn.media; //grab a reference to the actual video element

//make sure it's not playing
video.pause();

//clean up popcorn
popcorn.destroy();
popcorn.media = null; //popcorn should probably do this in destroy, but it doesn't

//clear the src, Make sure it's no longer using the network.
video.src = '';
video.load();

//remove from the DOM. You won't see it anymore.
if (video.parentNode) {
    video.parentNode.removeChild(video);
}
```

You'll also want to clear any other references you may have to the video, and it probably couldn't hurt to remove any event listeners you may have added, whether directly on the video element or through Popcorn.

Comment: even destroy does not work for me. I have actually used popcorn.load() which resets the media. I don't know why it worked for me, but I am glad it did. My plan was to interpret an audio while it is being played and then stop it. thank you anyway

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked out. `popcorn.destroy()` is not enough to do it. It's just one step of clean-up.